# Silverlight UI Freezes When Rendering Multiple DataGrids

Tags: silverlight, performance, user-interface, datagrid

I'm experiencing issues with the Silverlight UI (and indeed the browser) freezing when databinding/rendering datagrids. I have been able to reproduce the issue with the code below which uses 4 grids. In practice we will be using more than 4 grids.

I've found that if I only have a single grid and many more rows (e.g. 3000) everything is fine.

It looks like there there is contention between the four datagrids when they are trying to bind/render which is causing the UI to lockup.

Is this a known issue with silverlight? What work arounds are there?

**Code to reproduce problem**

Data object:

```
public class DataObject
{
    public string Column0 { get; set; }
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Column30 { get; set; }

    public DataObject()
    {
        Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        Column0 = r.Next(1000).ToString();
        Column1 = r.Next(1000).ToString();
        Column2 = r.Next(1000).ToString();
        ...
        Column30 = r.Next(1000).ToString();
    }
}
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataObject> _data = new ObservableCollection<DataObject>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PopulateData();

        DataContext = _data;
    }

    private void PopulateData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            _data.Add(new DataObject());
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DataObject> Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set { _data = value; }

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightGridTest.MainPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:sdk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                  Width="800"
                  Height="700"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column0, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column1, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column2, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    ...
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column30, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />

                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
            <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                  Width="800"
                  Height="700"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column0, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column1, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column2, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    ...
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column30, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />

                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
            <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                  Width="800"
                  Height="700"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column0, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column1, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column2, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    ...
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column30, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />

                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
            <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                  Width="800"
                  Height="700"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column0, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column1, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column2, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    ...
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column30, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />

                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Seems like a very contrived example. Can you provide a real world use case for where you need four datagrids bound to the same data on the same page?

Comment: We're binding to different datsets in the realworld. Are you suggesting that binding to a single dataset is part of the problem?

Comment: Works fine for me when I test it. There is a slight delay, but it doesn't freeze. I have all the exact same code (even all the columns you left out).

Comment: How are you distinguishing between a delay and freezing? I've found setting autogeneratecolumns to true which doubles the columns (yes it is contrived, but it illustrates the problem :)) makes the freezing even more obvious. Is there a limit on the number of columns that can be displayed? In the application I'm working on, we need to display data for multiple currencies, and risk measurments across each etc on a single page so we are using a lot of columns in different grids.

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing similar issues related to rendering DataGrids. Have you already solved the problem? Have you tried other data grid components?

Comment: We found there was a 1 or 2 second overhead to load each datagrid. We ended up using a plain xaml grid rather than a datagrid as it was read only data we were displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a data pager to only show a certain amount of rows at one time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the number of rows isn't the issue. I stated in my question that I can increase the rows to 3000 in a single grid and there is no problem.

Comment: I tried your code with 3000 rows * 30 columns. Loading 4 DataGrids takes about 4 times as loading a single one. DataGrid uses virtualisation, so that's why loading one is fast, and loading 4 of them is not that slow from what I just tried.

Comment: I've done some further testing today and it looks like there is an fixed cost (of around 2s in our environment) with loading a datagrid. Our UI needs to display tens of data tables so we're working on a solution that doesn't use a datagrid to display the data and it's much faster.

Comment: Generally speaking DataGrid is designed for displaying large amount of data. If it still takes time to load up, why not try a DataPager?